# Angular HttpParams Set Number Value Error

Tags: angular

I want to send the data I getfrom the form with angular to the backend. But I get an error when I add number value tı (params.set) part.

Error:Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

```
Name=ALex (string)
No:323678(number)

this.personel.name = this.form.get("name").value;
this.personel.no = this.form.get("no").value;


let params = new HttpParams();

if (personel.name != '')
  params = params.set('name', personel.name);
  
if (personel.no != '')
  params = params.set('no', personel.no);
```

---

```
export class Personel {

      personelId:number;
      name:string;
      surname:string;
      no:number;
      ...
}
```

Comment: As it's telling you, the parameter values must be strings. Converting a number to a string is a trivial JS task, not specific to Angular or even TypeScript.

Comment: If you want to convert to a number, just use + symbol. Ex: let p:number = +4;

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to send a request to a backend API is to use the angulat Http module. You can simply set an object as your parameters and all the work is handled by it.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient)

url = 'http://example.com/api';
data = {
    data1: 'Hello'
}
this.http.post(url, data).then(...);
```

works like a charm!